# How to communicate between tasks in an AWS ECS Fargate implementation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ecs

I have a standard implementation of an ALB in front of an ECS cluster running multiple services. These services are scaled based on CPU utilization so the number of tasks can vary throughout the day. The multiple services are in 1 VPC.
If I want the network traffic to be balanced then it would appear that I should go through the ALB. DNS would not provide that balancing.
What is the best way for a service to communicate with another service in the ECS cluster?

Comment: There a zillons of ways for computers to communicate, both within a single cluster and outside of it. Could you please expand a little bit on the problem you're trying to solve? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-connecting-services.html) for more guidance, but the easiest options are Cloud Map or an internal load balancer.

Using Cloud Map would be simpler to stand up because you don't have to worry as much about adding security groups and configuration for the load balancer.

Setting up an internal ALB has a few benefits:

- Easy to have your service scale by request count in addition to CPU/Memory.
- An ALB offers helpful aspects such as a Load Balancer Health Check

Cons:

- More expensive, at least $10/month. Check some of their [pricing examples](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/) for more info.